# What does "text degeneration" mean?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, terminology

In machine learning, especially NLP, **what does it mean to degenerate a text?**

I heard this phrase some days ago in my office and after googling it I saw there are some papers for it, so I thought it might be important and I'm here to aks about the terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This termin, according to [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09751), means the situations in text generation process when eigther generator model find the state **x** such that **G(x) = x** which means that generated text is repeated infinitely, or, according to error state in the middle of generation process, the model starts to reproduce incoherent text patterns.